# Repeated Measures ANOVA in SAS

Tags: sas

I currently have a dataset that contains several participants with multiple dependent variables represented by the means of the participants trials. The dependent variables are split into 6 levels each represented by a column and single value for each participant. These levels correspond to the 2 independent variables I am focused on, one having 3 factors and one having 2. I am attempting to perform repeated measures ANOVAs using the PROC GLM command in SAS On Demand, however I have been having trouble getting the code to return anything useful. The table below is an example of one of the dependent variables in the dataset. I would like to conduct multiple factorial repeated measures ANOVAs on each of my dependents and their 6 total factors. Can anyone give me some guidance? The questions I am struggling with are how to conduct the PROC GLM without having a CLASS statement, and how to test for homogeneity of variance using something like Levene's test?

| Subject | Dep1 (1_1) | Dep1 (1_2) | Dep1 (2_1) | Dep1 (2_2) | Dep1 (3_1) | Dep1 (3_2) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | value | value | value | value | value | value |
| 2 | value | value | value | value | value | value |

Comment: Hey Joewa! I recommend asking this on the SAS Community Stats Forum or in cross-validated on Stack Overflow for a faster answer.

Comment: Hellp, please look at: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/faq/how-can-i-perform-a-repeated-measures-anova-with-proc-mixed/ . Do you   allow to treat subject number as a group in proc glm procedure?